# Accessing rgbMat value in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to print out the values of rgbMat (in the below code) after mapping but getting some error. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? It's showing me the following error:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` line1.cpp 
l1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
l1.cpp:28:50: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘rgbMat’, which is of non-class type ‘CvMat*’
l1.cpp:28:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
l1.cpp:28:62: error: name lookup of ‘x’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
l1.cpp:28:62: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

I guess I am going wrong in the following line:

```
  printf("matrix is %u: \n", rgbMat.at<uchar>(y,x));
```

My code is:

```
     IplImage* rgb[3];

     float L0[]={
         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        -1,-1,-1,-1,-1 };

     CvMat*  rgbMat = cvCreateMat(5, 5, CV_32FC1);

     for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
     {
         for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
             cvmSet(rgbMat, y, x, L0[y*5 + x]);
           printf("matrix is %u: \n", rgbMat.at<uchar>(y,x));
     }
```

Comment: You are calling cv::mat::at() at a struct from the C-api that won't work. Use cv::Mat for C++ api function.

Comment: To convert from CvMat to cv::Mat, construct `cv::Mat rgbMatcpp(rgbMat)`. You can then use `rgbMatcpp.at<uchar>(x, y)`.

Comment: @Zaphod I did the CvMat to cv::Mat conversion then pritned as printf("matrix is %u: \n", rgbMatcpp.at<uchar>(x, y));    but still it's giving me the following errors: line1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
l1.cpp:28:63: warning: name lookup of ‘x’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
l1.cpp:26:23: warning:   using obsolete binding at ‘x

Comment: These occur because the scope of your `x` and `y` variables are limited to their `for` loops. Since you haven't used braces for the inner `for` loop, `x` is destroyed after the call to `cvmSet`. Use braces and put the `printf` inside the inner `for` loop.

Comment: And be wary of your use of `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` in the `printf`. I inadvertantly used `(x,y)` in my comment, but I think you need `(y,x)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32896/discussion-between-user2481422-and-zaphod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the discussion:

It is advisable to port all use of OpenCV matrices to the new cv::Mat format. However, OpenCV provides functionality to [convert between the old and new formats](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

> Partial yet very common cases of this user-allocated data case are conversions from CvMat and IplImage to Mat. For this purpose, there are special constructors taking pointers to CvMat or IplImage and the optional flag indicating whether to copy the data or not. Backward conversion from Mat to CvMat or IplImage is provided via cast operators Mat::operator CvMat() const and Mat::operator IplImage(). The operators do NOT copy the data.

In your code, first convert `rgbMat` to the `cv::Mat` format using `cv::Mat rgbMatcpp(rgbMat)`. Now you should be able to access elements using `at`. For example, `rgbMatcpp.at<float>(y, x)`. Next, be wary that variables `x` and `y` are limited in their scope to the `for` loops that they operate in. So use braces for the inner `for` loop and move the `printf` into the loop body. Also, in your attempt at using `at`, you have specified the type as `uchar`, which is erroneous because rgbMat is of type `CV_32FC1`. So change your use of `at` to `rgbMatcpp.at<float>(y, x)`.